# New date with weekend

Tags: php, datetime

```
$date = new DateTime("11:00");
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i W');
```

this create new datetime which is now with hour 11:00:

2011-12-22 11:00 51

how can i make it with W - weekend? 
i would like create new date with hour 11:00 and week 20. (now is 51)

How can i make it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime("11:00");
$date->format('W H:i');
```

the format method accepts the same format identifier as the [`date`](http://fr.php.net/date) function. The `W` return the week number.

Comment: i know, but i would like receive this date with week 20, not 51 (now is 51)

Comment: i would like create simply calendar. 20 this is example.